# Site code to enable UTF-8 to EBCDIC encoding

Tags: utf-8, ftp, zos, ebcdic, mojibake

I'm trying to transmit a rather large UTF-8 file to a Z/OS dataset. Unfortunately, the command

```
SITE EN=MBCS MBD=(1047,1208) RECFM=VB
TYPE A
STOR STORE.WRK.DATA
```

responds with

```
504 Multi-byte encoding not supported for RECFM=FB
```

It seems the `RECFM=VB` doesn't work.

The workaround is to recode UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 before uploading, but encoding while uploading is more efficient.

Comment: So what's your question? How are you encoding it now?

Comment: The original file, being encoded in UTF-8, is transcoded to ISO_8859-1, then uploaded using FTP in ASCII mode to a Z/OS dataset. I'm looking for a way to configure ASCII mode FTP to accept UTF-8 directly.

Comment: Just a caution...UTF-8 of course can represent more characters than ISO-8859, so you should be prepared for the possibility of data loss if there is in fact a multibyte sequence in your UTF-8 file that can't be expressed in ASCII. The underlying "iconv()" routine isn't pleasant when it detects this.

Comment: One other thing...I find UNIX Services files are your friend when it comes to this sort of thing. Assuming your site has it setup correctly, changing your STOR to reference a path (./store.wrk.data) will make many of these issues go away - there's generally no such thing as RECFM for a UNIX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to making this work might be multifaceted.

First, the site in question must have the conversion from IBM-1047 to IBM 1208 defined in Unicode Conversion Services for z/OS.  If it isn't, the attempt to covert will fail.

Second, you can't send an single byte per character code page to a dataset sized for that, but turn it into a multi byte per character code page.  If any of the characters in that dataset grow to two or three bytes, the record length is going to cause failure.  So transmit it to a variable record length dataset, and you will be fine.

Comment: As it turns out, we have to preprocess the file anyway, so we kept the  conversion code.
`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(inputdoc.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));`
`BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(outputdoc.getOutputStream(), "Windows-1252"));`